# can't load post from api

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to retrieve post from the api using redux but it doesn't load any post from the api. It does load the dummy snippets I've created in the initialState but not the posts that are saved in the database using the api. What wrong am I doing in trying to retrieve the posts from my api?

My action file where I made the api call

```
import { SAVE_POST, UPDATE_POST, RETRIEVE_POST, HOME_LOADED } from "./types";
import axios from "axios";
export const savePost = ({
  snippetId,
  snippetDescription,
  snippetTitle
}) => async dispatch => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  };
  let snippetData = { snippetId, snippetDescription, snippetTitle };
  try {
    if (snippetId == null) {
      const res = await axios.post(
        "/api/save",
        JSON.stringify(snippetData),
        config
      );
      snippetData.snippetId = res.data;
      dispatch({
        type: SAVE_POST,
        payload: snippetData
      });
    } else {
      await axios.post("/api/update", JSON.stringify(snippetData), config);
      dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_POST,
        payload: snippetData
      });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

// Retrieve post

export const retrievePost = snippetId => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.post(`/api/snippetdata/${snippetId}`);
    dispatch({
      type: RETRIEVE_POST,
      payload: res.data
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};

//Retrieve all the post
export const onLoad = () => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.post(`/api/mysnippets/`);
    dispatch({
      type: HOME_LOADED,
      payload: res.data
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

the home page where I call the action to retrieve the post

```
import React from "react";
// import axios from "axios";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { onLoad, setEdit } from "./actions/posts";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

// import { Form } from "../../components/Article";

class Home extends React.Component {
  // constructor(props) {
  //   super(props);
  // }

  componentDidMount() {
    //Load all the snippets
    onLoad(); // this isn't loading the post from server
  }

  render() {
    const { snippets } = this.props;
    console.log(this.props);
    let view;
    if (snippets) {
      view = snippets.map(snippet => {
        return (
          <div className="card my-3" key={snippet.snippetId}>
            <div className="card-header">{snippet.title}</div>
            <div className="card-body">{snippet.snippetDescription}</div>
            <div className="card-footer">
              <div className="row">
                <button
                  // onClick={() => this.handleEdit(snippet)}
                  className="btn btn-primary mx-3"
                >
                  <Link to={`/editor/:${snippet.snippetId}`}>Edit</Link>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      });
    }

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row pt-5">
          <div className="col-12 col-lg-6 offset-lg-3">
            <h1 className="text-center">Snippets</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row pt-5">
          <div className="col-12 col-lg-6 offset-lg-3">{view}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  snippets: state.snippets,
  snippetData: state.snippetData
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { onLoad, setEdit }
)(Home);
```

reducer.js

```
import {
  SAVE_POST,
  UPDATE_POST,
  RETRIEVE_POST,
  HOME_LOADED
} from "../actions/types";

import { initialState } from "../store";

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  switch (type) {
    case SAVE_POST:
      return {
        ...state,
        snippetData: payload
      };
    case UPDATE_POST:
      return {
        ...state,
        snippetData: payload
      };
    case RETRIEVE_POST:
      return {
        ...state,
        snippetData: payload
      };
    case HOME_LOADED:
      return {
        ...state,
        snippets: payload
      };
    case "SET_EDIT":
      return {
        ...state,
        snippetToEdit: action.snippet
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-dijkstra-7u3o4) of the entire webapp

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 I added the reducer file and the full code is in the codesandbox too

Comment: The `onLoad` action is sending a `post` request.  Is that intentional?

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 yeah, it is intentional. isn't onLoad suppose to call the api and receive the posts from the server?

Comment: I can't see your server code but usually retrieving data without supplying parameters is a `GET` request.

Comment: i was told to migrate the website from angular to react. the angular guy who left did the retrieving of posts using `POST` request. i think it can be done with `POST` request too

Comment: Is the submitted snippet being updated in the database?

Comment: I haven't worked with the save feature yet because I haven't figured that either but there are already snippets in the database which I'm not able to retrieve.

Comment: Maybe you have some defaults assigned to Axios, like a JSON auth code or something, which might require it to be a post request, not sure.  I don't use Axios, kinda for this very reason that it can be confusing, too implicit, plus it's largely unnecessary considering that the Fetch API has broad support these days, but I digress.

Comment: I didn't assign anything to axios.. even the authentication is done in the backend, I didn't do any authentication in the frontend using jwt either

Comment: I would make sure that the `onLoad` action is actually being called.  Log the response from the action and make sure an error isn't being thrown.  Installing Redux dev tools would make this easier for you, but you can deal with that later since it's a bit of a process to set up.  You could also search the codebase for [axios.default](https://github.com/axios/axios#config-defaults) and try changing the request to a `GET` request if sending a `POST` request doesn't make sense..

Comment: I was reading an article and stumble upon redux thunk. should  I use redux thunk here since its an async request

Comment: @henrydoe seems like you are not using middleware (like thunk) in your application to handle async calls.

Comment: Yes, `redux-thunk` is required if you want to have async actions that use the `dispatch` and/or `getState` functions.  Assigning `redux-thunk` is done once in your Redux store file, though, not individually in your action files.

Answer (score 2):

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import posts from "./reducers/posts";

export const initialState = {
  snippets: [
    {
      snippetId: "1",
      snippetTitle: "test",
      snippetDescription: "test test"
    },
    {
      snippetId: "2",
      snippetTitle: "post2",
      snippetDescription: "post 2 post2"
    }
  ],
  snippetData: {
    snippetId: null,
    snippetTitle: null,
    snippetDescription: null
  }
};
const store = createStore(posts, applyMiddleware(thunk));
export default store;
```

Above is the store.js file which has to be updated with middleware.

Since you are making network calls, you got to use a middleware like redux thunk to handle async operations as basic redux store only allows you to do the synchronous updates but not async. These help us to return a function rather than action. Hope this helps!

```
//Dispatch function:
    export const onLoad = () => {
      return async dispatch => {
        console.log("dispatched");
        try {
          const res = axios.post(`/api/mysnippets/`);
          dispatch({
            type: HOME_LOADED,
            payload: res.data
          });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: should I make any changes in the action file too? for the dispatch function?

Comment: Yeah I have updated the dispatch function in the answer above :)

Comment: the onLoad action is not being fired when loaded